React Native Header title with flex elipse and right icon
I am trying to get this flex situation fixed on the title, where if its a long title you get the ellipse, but if short its centered with the v icon to the immediate right like in the first screenshot, but there is this spacing that wont go away because of the flex: 1.  Is there a way to accomplish this?


<AppView
            paddingHorizontal={5}
            useButton={dropDown}
            onPress={onTitlePress}
            flexDirection="row"
            justifyContent="center"
            flex={true}
            alignItems="center">
            <AppText
             style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
              textColor="text"
              textAlign='center'
              isDarkTheme={isDarkTheme}
              numberOfLines={1}
              fontSize={AppFonts[17]}
              fontFamily="DMSansBold">
              Little
            </AppText>
            {dropDown ? (
              <AppView flexDirection='row' style={{paddingLeft: 2, width: 30}}>
              <FontAwesomeSvg
                iconType="SolidIcons"
                color={getAppColor('text', 1, isDarkTheme)}
                icon={'faAngleDown'}
                size={12}
              />
               </AppView>
            ) : null}
          </AppView>

